# How to use a variable as a name for Another Function in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, pip, names

Hi stackoverflow users,

my question is quite straigtforward:

How can I use a variable in the name of another command?

My Script looks roughly like this:

```
    for i in range(1, face_recognition_core_count+1):
    face_finder+i = multiprocessing.Process(target=find_faces, args=(total_frame_count, i))
    face_finder+i.start()
    face_finder+i.join()
```

Comment: Don't. Just add the processes to a list, then do `processes[i]` (or whatever you call the list) to retrieve them.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary.

```
face_finder_dict = {}
for i in range(1, face_recognition_core_count + 1):
    face_finder_dict[f"face_finder{i}"] = multiprocessing.Process(target=find_faces, args=(total_frame_count, i))
    face_finder_dict[f"face_finder{i}"].start()
    face_finder_dict[f"face_finder{i}"].join()
```

Comment: @marcr I edited the code to use a string name. I thought you had defined face_finder in your example code in the original post.

Comment: Hi, this also doesn't seem to works, because the started Process has the same name. So it will only create one Process named face_finder_dict and the other ones will have the same name and cannot be created.

Comment: the first process will be the value of face_finder_dict[f"face_finder0"], the second one the value of face_finder_dict[f"face_finder1"] and so on. why do they have the same name?

Comment: I think python ignores the [...] on .start and .join. I dont know how to bypass this.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. I first need to define all of the Multiprocessing functions and only after that start them.